# Jhipster custom elasticsearch mapping

Tags: java, elasticsearch, jhipster

I am looking for information about how Jhipster creates the mapping for elasticsearch. I would also like to customise this mapping as the default mapping for a relationship between two entities doesn't specify its type as a parent or child or even nested. This limits how I can use elastic search.

For example, I have two entities generated with the following jdl:

```
entity Event {
    title String required minlength(1) maxlength(30)
    startDate ZonedDateTime required,
    endDate ZonedDateTime required

}

entity CustomData{
    name String required minlength(1) maxlength(30),
    value String required,
    filterable Boolean required     
}

 relationship OneToMany{
    Event{aEvent} to CustomData{Event(id)}
 }
```

This relationship isn't saved to the search repository by default and only allows Events with 'child' objects of CustomData attached as an array of objects.

Here is an example of how this looks:

```
{
        "id": 28152,
        "title": "testWed123",
        "startDate": "2019-02-13T10:53:00.798Z",
        "endDate": "2019-02-13T10:53:00.798Z",
        "customData": [
            {
                "id": 28202,
                "name": "customData1",
                "value": "customDataValue1",
                "filterable": false,
                "event": null
            },
            {
                "id": 28203,
                "name": "customData1",
                "value": "customDataValue2",
                "filterable": true,
                "event": null
            }
        ]
    }
```

And here is how I am saving these events to the elasticsearch repository:

```
event.addCustomData(customData1);
eventSearchRepository.save(event);
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a way to use custom mapping, however i did find out how to use the automatic mapping to achieve the above, Simply use the below annotation in the parent class to describe the relationship.

```
    @Field(type = FieldType.Nested, includeInParent = true)
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "event", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity = CustomData.class)
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    private Set<CustomData> customData = new HashSet<>();
```

use a different Index name if you have placed any documents in the index as it will no generate a new mapping with the above information.